# How to demonstrate Taubah?

Tags: practical-islam, allah, sin, tawba

As-salamu Alaykum,

I am aware that Tawba’s conditions are to stop doing the sin, regretting and resolving never to do it again.

Now my question is, is this something you orally declare you are doing? For example you make supplication to Allah SWT telling Him this?

Or is this an action from your heart? For instance, you’ve stopped doing the sin, you regret it and you have the intention never to do it again.

Jazak Allahu Khayran for passing on your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

As for as Isthighfar and tawba is concerned its a matter of heart in islam unlike christianity wherein you have to orally say it to a pastor to have your sin forgiven, in islam there is no such condition. When a person sins, he needs to gain back his consciousness, regret the sin he/she committed and seek forgiveness to Allah with a firm resolve to never go back and mend his life turning back to Allah (tawba). If you wish you could say it orally or resolve it in your heart of not going back to sin. Remember its allah, no matter which one you chose to do, it would make no difference as Allah says

...Allah knows what you conceal and what you declare. And Allah is Knowing of that within the breasts.. (64:4)

Do use this supplication for [isthighfar](https://bit.ly/2XEXFQd), as is the best of all.

Istighfaar means seeking forgiveness, while Tawba means turning to Allah leaving behind the sins.

Comment: May Allah SWT bless you for such a good response. Thank you so much sister.